# Make 3 levels of difficulties in a quiz app

Tags: java, android, algorithm

I am developing a simple quiz app on Android. The questions in the quiz should become more difficult as advancing in the quiz. Now, I am trying to implement a static method that takes a list of `Question` objects and produces (pick) a sub-list of the appropriate questions depending on the difficulty and it should be ordered (First question in the list is the simplest one). The app has 3 levels (modes) of difficulties.

Here is the method snippet:

```
public static List<Question> getQuestions(List<Question> availableQuestions,
                                       int quizDifficulty, int numberOfQuestion)
{
    if(availableQuestions.size() < numberOfQuestion)
        throw NotEnoughQuestionsException();

    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>(numberOfQuestion);
    if(quizDifficulty == 0) // Easy
    {
        // ...
        return questions;
    }
    else if(quizDifficulty == 2) // Hard
    {
        // ...
        return questions;   
    }
    else /*if(quizDifficulty == 1)*/ // Normal
    {
        // ...
        return questions;
    }
}
```

Each `Question` object has a field `difficulty` which is in range `1 (most simple)` to `10 (most difficult)`, and this field can be access by `getDifficulty()` method.

As I though of a way to implement the method, I decided to make the questions' difficulties should not exceed level `8` for `Easy` mode, and they should be more than level `3` in the `Hard` mode, and in between level `9` and level `2` in the `Normal` mode.

The problem is that the provided list of questions `availableQuestions` is not guaranteed to contain all the required levels of difficulties, for example, all the questions are in level 1.

So, my question is, what is the best idea to implement this method?

---

**EDIT:**

Here is my progress so far:

```
public static List<Question> getQuestions(List<Question> availableQuestions,
                                      int quizDifficulty, int numberOfQuestion)
{
    if(availableQuestions.size() < numberOfQuestion)
        throw NotEnoughQuestionsException();

    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>(numberOfQuestion);
    Map<Integer, List<Question>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Question>>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) map.put(i, new ArrayList<Question>());
    for(Question question : availableQuestions) 
        map.get(question.getDifficulty()).add(question);

    int L1 = map.get(1).size(); // number of questions with level 1
    int L2 = map.get(2).size();
    int L3 = map.get(3).size();
    int L4 = map.get(4).size();
    int L5 = map.get(5).size();
    int L6 = map.get(6).size();
    int L7 = map.get(7).size();
    int L8 = map.get(8).size();
    int L9 = map.get(9).size();
    int L10 = map.get(10).size();

    final int L1_TO_L8  = 0;
    final int L1_TO_L9  = 1;
    final int L1_TO_L10 = 2;
    final int L2_TO_L9  = 3;
    final int L2_TO_L10 = 4;
    final int L3_TO_L10 = 5;

    int status;

    if(difficulty == 0) // Easy (level 1 to level 8)
    {
        int missing = questionsCount - (L1+L2+L3+L4+L5+L6+L7+L8);
        if(missing > 0) // not enough questions in L1 through L8
        {
            if(missing - L9 > 0) // we must include all the level
            {
                status = L1_TO_L10;
            }
            else // enough questions in L1 through L9
            {
                status = L1_TO_L9;
            }
        }
        else // enough questions in L1 through L8
        {
            status = L1_TO_L8;
        }
    }
    else if(difficulty == 2) // Hard (level 3 to level 10)
    {
        int missing = questionsCount - (L3+L4+L5+L6+L7+L8+L9+L10);
        if(missing > 0) // not enough questions in L3 through L10
        {
            if(missing - L2 > 0) // we must include all the level
            {
                status = L1_TO_L10;
            }
            else // enough questions in L2 through L10
            {
                status = L2_TO_L10;
            }
        }
        else // enough questions in L3 through L10
        {
            status = L3_TO_L10;
        }
    }
    else /*if(difficulty == 1)*/ // Normal (level 2 to level 9)
    {
        int missing = questionsCount - (L2+L3+L4+L5+L6+L7+L8+L9);
        if(missing > 0) // not enough questions in L2 through L9
        {
            if(missing - L1 > 0) // we must include all the level
            {
                status = L1_TO_L10;
            }
            else // enough questions in L1 through L9
            {
                status = L1_TO_L9;
            }
        }
        else // enough questions in L2 through L9
        {
            status = L2_TO_L9;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The only possible answer is:  if there are no questions of the required difficulty, return questions of a nearby difficulty instead, or none at all *(depending on your app's requirements)*.  Is there a real question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented my own algorithm and it works just perfect, though it has a lot of duplicated codes:

```
public static List<Question> getQuestions(List<Question> availableQuestions,
                                      int quizDifficulty, int numberOfQuestion)
{
    if(availableQuestions.size() < numberOfQuestion)
        throw NotEnoughQuestionsException();

    List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>(numberOfQuestion);
    Map<Integer, List<Question>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Question>>();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) map.put(i, new ArrayList<Question>());
    for(Question question : availableQuestions) 
    map.get(question.getDifficulty()).add(question);

    int L1 = map.get(1).size(); // number of questions with level 1
    int L2 = map.get(2).size();
    int L3 = map.get(3).size();
    int L4 = map.get(4).size();
    int L5 = map.get(5).size();
    int L6 = map.get(6).size();
    int L7 = map.get(7).size();
    int L8 = map.get(8).size();
    int L9 = map.get(9).size();
    int L10 = map.get(10).size();

    final int L1_TO_L8  = 0;
    final int L1_TO_L9  = 1;
    final int L1_TO_L10 = 2;
    final int L2_TO_L9  = 3;
    final int L2_TO_L10 = 4;
    final int L3_TO_L10 = 5;

    int status;

    if(difficulty == 0) // Easy (level 1 to level 8)
    {
        int missing = questionsCount - (L1+L2+L3+L4+L5+L6+L7+L8);
        if(missing > 0) // not enough questions in L1 through L8
        {
            if(missing - L9 > 0) // we must include all the level
            {
                status = L1_TO_L10;
            }
            else // enough questions in L1 through L9
            {
                status = L1_TO_L9;
            }
        }
        else // enough questions in L1 through L8
        {
            status = L1_TO_L8;
        }
    }
    else if(difficulty == 2) // Hard (level 3 to level 10)
    {
        int missing = questionsCount - (L3+L4+L5+L6+L7+L8+L9+L10);
        if(missing > 0) // not enough questions in L3 through L10
        {
            if(missing - L2 > 0) // we must include all the level
            {
                status = L1_TO_L10;
            }
            else // enough questions in L2 through L10
            {
                status = L2_TO_L10;
            }
        }
        else // enough questions in L3 through L10
        {
            status = L3_TO_L10;
        }
    }
    else /*if(difficulty == 1)*/ // Normal (level 2 to level 9)
    {
        int missing = questionsCount - (L2+L3+L4+L5+L6+L7+L8+L9);
        if(missing > 0) // not enough questions in L2 through L9
        {
            if(missing - L1 > 0) // we must include all the level
            {
                status = L1_TO_L10;
            }
            else // enough questions in L1 through L9
            {
                status = L1_TO_L9;
            }
        }
        else // enough questions in L2 through L9
        {
            status = L2_TO_L9;
        }
    }

    if(status == L1_TO_L8) // Look into level 1 through level 8 only
    {
        int q = 0;
        for(int level = 1; level <= 8 && q < numberOfQuestion; level += 8 * q <= numberOfQuestion * level? 0 : 1)
        {
            if(level == 1)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 2)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 3)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 4)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 5)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 6)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 7)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 8)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
            }
        }
    }
    else if(status == L1_TO_L9)
    {
        int q = 0;
        for(int level = 1; level <= 9 && q < numberOfQuestion; level += 9 * q <= numberOfQuestion * level? 0 : 1)
        {
            if(level == 1)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 2)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 3)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 4)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 5)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 6)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 7)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 8)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 9)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 1)){q++; continue;}
            }
        }
    }
    else if(status == L2_TO_L9)
    {
        int q = 0;
        for(int level = 2; level <= 9 && q < numberOfQuestion; level += 9 * q <= numberOfQuestion * level? 0 : 1)
        {
            if(level == 2)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 3)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 4)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 5)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 6)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 7)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 8)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 9)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
            }
        }
    }
    else if(status == L2_TO_L10)
    {
        int q = 0;
        for(int level = 2; level <= 10 && q < numberOfQuestion; level += 10 * q <= numberOfQuestion * level? 0 : 1)
        {
            if(level == 2)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 3)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 4)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 5)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 6)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 7)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 8)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 9)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 10)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 2)){q++; continue;}
            }
        }
    }
    else if(status == L3_TO_L10)
    {
        int q = 0;
        for(int level = 3; level <= 10 && q < numberOfQuestion; level += 10 * q <= numberOfQuestion * level? 0 : 1)
        {
            if(level == 3)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 4)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 5)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 6)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 7)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 8)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 9)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
            }
            else if(level == 10)
            {
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 10)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 9)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 8)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 7)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 6)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 5)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 4)){q++; continue;}
                if(check(readyQuestionsList, map, 3)){q++; continue;}
            }
        }
    }
    else /*if(status == L1_TO_L10)*/
    {
        // same idea is implemented here
    }
    return questions;
}

private boolean check(List<Question> readyQuestionsList, Map<Integer, List<Question>> map, int level)
{
    if(map.get(level).size() > 0 && map.get(level).get(0) != null)
    {
        readyQuestionsList.add(map.get(level).remove(0));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the simplest solution is get all questions that have certain level depending on your mode, then you can sort this list , for example:

```
public static List<Question> getQuestions(List<Question> availableQuestions, 
     int quizDifficulty, int numberOfQuestion)
  {
      if(availableQuestions.size() < numberOfQuestion)
          throw NotEnoughQuestionsException();

      List<Question> questionsForUserMode = getQuestionsFromMode(
                        availableQuestions, quizDifficulty); 

       // sort this questionsForUserMode by Difficulty using comprator
  }

  // please put these magic numbers in constant fields or enum :)
  public static List<Question> getQuestionsFromMode (List<Question> questions,
             int mode) {
    if ( mode == 1 ) {
      return getQuestionsWithCertainLevel(questions, 1, 8);
    }
    else if ( moode == 2 ) {
      return getQuestionsWithCertainLevel(questions, 2, 9);
    }
    else
      return getQuestionsWithCertainLevel(questions, 3, 10);
  }

  private static List<Question> getQuestionsWithCertainLevel(
          List<Question> questions, int fromLeve, int toLevel) {
    List<Question> subQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();

    for(Question question: questions) {
      if ( question.getDifficulty() >= fromLevel &&
           question.getDifficulty() <= toLevel ) {
        subQuestions.add(question);
      }
    }

    return subQuestions;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start by sorting the questions after the requirement, implement different sorting algorithms for the different levels (putting the most relevant questions for the current difficulty level first). Then it is just to pick questions starting from the beginning of the list.

Something like this:

```
static final int[] easy = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
static final int[] medium = {3,4,5,6,7,8};
static final int[] hard = {4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

public static List<Question> getQuestions(List<Question> availableQuestions,
        int quizDifficulty, int numberOfQuestion){

     if(quizDifficulty == 0) // Easy
         Collections.sort(availableQuestions, new CompareQuestion(easy));
     else if(quizDifficulty == 2) // Hard
         Collections.sort(availableQuestions, new CompareQuestion(hard));
     else if(quizDifficulty == 1) // Normal
         Collections.sort(availableQuestions, new CompareQuestion(medium));

    int questions  = availableQuestions.size();
    return availableQuestions.subList(0, numberOfQuestion <= questions ? numberOfQuestion : questions);
}

static class CompareQuestion implements Comparator<Question>{

    final int[] compareList;

    public CompareQuestion(int[] compareList){
        this.compareList = compareList;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Question q1, Question q2) {
        boolean o1wanted = inList(q1.difficulty, compareList);
        boolean o2wanted = inList(q2.difficulty, compareList);

        if(o1wanted && o2wanted) return 0;

        if(o1wanted && !o2wanted) return -1;

        return 1;
    }

    public boolean inList(int a, int[] list){
        for(int i : list) if(a == i) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do.

1. Start a loop over the list of questions.
2. Based upon the condition for EASY:NORMAL:HARD, I would add them to the list

   - if (easy)

     - if( difficulty < 8 )
     - add to list.
       .... Similarly for hard and normal.
3. At the end I would sort the sub-list, using one of the sorting algos.

In this case, if specied difficulty level is not met, then you end up having a empty question list (for the eg u mentioned, ie if all the questions are of difficulty level 1 and you request a hard difficulty).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I am readin your question correct. 
My suggestion is to do something with this format:

```
level|question
```

then when your question are being pushed into an array, seperate the level from the question.

I don't know Java but here is the idea with objective-c

```
NSArray* components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
NSString* level = [components objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* question = [components objectAtIndex:1];
```

then compare if `level == selectedLevel`

I always found this the easiest considering your question and its level are side by side and no need to worry that the question and its level wont match.